# How can I force the background to fill the screen Tailwind/CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I need the dark grey background to fill the screen but I don't want overflow. Setting the page to 100vh + overflow hidden won't work because it takes out our footer.

Thanks.

[image: Whitespace under site]

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the relevant markup to your question and illustrate what you've tried so far.